# Arrange one c# List using swapping performed by another List while sorting

Tags: c#, sorting

I have two  c# Lists , when I sort one List based on certain camparator, I need to sort another list following the swappings performed by first list without using much extra space.

```
//function 
private int ColumnSortCriteria(List<double> p1, List<double> p2) 
{
    if (p1[0] > p2[0])
        return 1;
    if ((float) p1[0] == (float) p2[0] && p2[1] > p2[1])
        return 1;
    if (p1[0] == p2[0] && p1[1] == p2[1])
        return 0;
    return -1;
}
// main goes from here ......
List<List<double>> WallEndPoints1 = new List<List<double>>();
List<List<double>> WallEndPoints2 = new List<List<double>>();
WallEndPoints1.sort(ColumnSortCriteria)
```

Comment: May be *combine* both lists into one? Say `List<Tuple<Double, Double>>` and then sort by the 1st component?

Comment: Why the cast to `float`?

Comment: Do `p1` and `p2` always have a `Count` of exactly two? Are they really 2D points?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Stig Nielsen 1  that is just a example of decision function whether to swap two list or not. main question is how to  maintain that swaping order to another list without directly merging and using extra space

Comment: Just find any existing open source sort routine, and replace any "swap" actions with a delegate callback with the two positions that should be swapped.  Then you can do the sorting on as many lists as you want simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a comment (but long).

From you sort criteria method, I infer that your `p1` and `p2` (hence your "inner" `List<>`) always have a `Count` of two. Then why not use `Tuple<double, double>` for them? Then you have:

```
List<Tuple<double, double>> WallEndPoints1 = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
List<Tuple<double, double>> WallEndPoints2 = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
```

You can add points to the lists like this:

```
WallEndPoints1.Add(Tuple.Create(7.3, -0.5));
// etc.
```

And your `ColumnSortCriteria` becomes simply:

```
//function 
static int ColumnSortCriteria(Tuple<double, double> p1, Tuple<double, double> p2) 
{
  // lexicographic
  return System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralComparer.Compare(p1, p2);
}
```

Then if, in the spirit of Dmitry's answer, you combine (zip) the two lists together, you get:

```
List<Tuple<Tuple<double, double>, Tuple<double, double>>> combinedEndPoints
  = WallEndPoints1.Zip(WallEndPoints2, Tuple.Create).ToList();
```

(a case for the `var` keyword?).

In that case you can sort like this:

```
combinedEndPoints.Sort((a, b) => ColumnSortCriteria(a.Item1, b.Item1));
```

It sorts the pairs of pairs by the first pair (`.Item1`), where first pairs are compared lexicographically. If first pairs are identical as pairs, the order is undefined.

To me, this is the most probable interpretation of your question.

Maybe what you want, is "simply":

```
combinedEndPoints.Sort(System.Collections.StructuralComparisons.StructuralComparer.Compare);
```

It sorts the list of pairs of pairs by a kind of "nested" or "deep" lexicographic ordering.

---

Of course, if you do not wish to follow my advice and change the types of `WallEndPoints1` and `WallEndPoints2` to include `Tuple<,>`, the solution still looks the same:

```
List<Tuple<List<double>, List<double>>> combinedEndPoints
  = WallEndPoints1.Zip(WallEndPoints2, Tuple.Create).ToList();

combinedEndPoints.Sort((a, b) => ColumnSortCriteria(a.Item1, b.Item1));
```

where `ColumnSortCriteria` is now your original method from the question (original signature).

In either case, as also Dmitry says in his answer, select a component from the "combined" list to see only "1" or only "2", that is:

```
var wallEndPoints1Sorted = combinedEndPoints.Select(x => x.Item1);
var wallEndPoints2Sorted = combinedEndPoints.Select(x => x.Item2);
```

Comment: Inner List contains Two points (point1.X is on 0, Point1.Y is on 1, point2.X is on 2 and so on ) and bunch of other information. but i am using only point1 in sorting criteria. so can not use tuple

Comment: @Gitesh See the new extension of this answer (below the horizontal ruler).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *combining* both lists into one:

```
// I've used Tuple<T1, T2>, but probably you have a better class for point
List<Tuple<Double, Double>> WallEndPoints = new List<Tuple<Double, Double>>() {
  new Tuple<Double, Double>(3.0, 5.0),
  ...
  new Tuple<Double, Double>(15.0, 20.0),
};
```

then sort by, say, 1st component:

```
WallEndPoints.Sort((left, right) => left.Item1.CompareTo(right.Item1));
```

or lexicograhicaly (by 1st component, on tie by 2nd one):

```
WallEndPoints.Sort((left, right) => {
  int result = left.Item1.CompareTo(right.Item1);

  return result != 0 ? result : left.Item2.CompareTo(right.Item2);  
});
```

whenever you want 1st/2nd components you can use *Linq*:

```
var xs = WallEndPoints.Select(item => item.Item1);
var ys = WallEndPoints.Select(item => item.Item2);
```

Comment: Maybe he wanted it lexicographical, so when first components are equal, use second components as a tie-breaker.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: a small modification of the lambda within the `Sort` function will do the lexicographical order.